# How do I remove these bathroom faucet fittings with limited space?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I have a faucet I am trying to remove to replace, seen below. It appears there is a nut holding it to the bottom of the sink, but I can't get a basin wrench around the nut and plumbers sockets won't fit over the threaded fitting:

[image]

I'm at a loss as to how this was assembled in the first place. It looks like the flexible copper line was sweated into the threaded fitting, which seems strange.

Here's a photo from another angle:

[image]

Here is a photo from the top in case that is helpful:

[image]

Comment: I strongly suspect that a lot of it was assembled in the first place before the sink was put in place. Which would be one possible approach to disassembly....

Comment: have you tried to unscrew the right side chrome flange in the bottom picture?

Comment: @jsotola I have tried removing the chrome flange, that's why the handle is disassembled. There doesn't seem to be a way to remove it, it doesn't spin and there is no good way to grab it with a wrench. I haven't tried prying it up yet

Answer (score 2):

First - Remove the chrome apron and see if there is a top nut holding the fixture from the top.

If the faucet cannot be removed from the top, then use this method.  Since you are replacing the faucet, I would just cut the copper pipe at the Tee inlet as shown in my picture or close at the end of the thread.  Do the cut which would allow you to unscrew the fitting.  Once the fitting is removed, then a plumber socket can be used to loosen the retaining nut.  I have done this on several faucets for friends who were replacing their fixtures.
[image]

Comment: there must be a nut at the top. the valve body is larger than the hole.